# My method should be iterating many many times but it isn't, why?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, arraylist, sudoku

I am writing a sudoku solving algorithm and I am trying to implement a deductive method for solving the puzzle. However I must have a loose grasp on recursion or something, because my algorithm only seems to change the board once at very most, even when a condition I am setting should return true most times. Here are my methods

```
public void CRME() {
    for (Node n : cells) {
        scanColumn(n);
        scanRow(n);
        scanMiniGrid(n);
        sortBoardVals();
    }
}
```

This scans each column, row and minigrid and knocks out possible values of each Node in an arraylist that represents the board.

```
    public void solve(){
    boolean canChange = false;
    ArrayList<Node> before = new ArrayList<Node>(cells);
    CRME();
    for(Node n : cells){
        int i = cells.indexOf(n);
        if(n.isEqual(before.get(i))){
            canChange = false;
        } else {
            canChange = true;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(canChange){
        System.out.println("Solving...");
        solve();
    }
}
```

This is the solve algorithm that should recall itself till it is absolutely exhausted.

And this is my node class

```
public class Node {
public ArrayList<Integer> posVals = new ArrayList<Integer>(9) {{
    add(1);
    add(2);
    add(3);
    add(4);
    add(5);
    add(6);
    add(7);
    add(8);
    add(9);
}};
private int ROW_ID;
private int COL_ID;
private int MG_ID;
static boolean hasChanged = true;

int value = 0;

public boolean isEqual(Node n){
    if(this.posVals.size() == n.posVals.size()){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
}
```

I might be considering a total rethink of my project because I'm thinking using an arraylist is over complicating the problem.

The methods within CRME basically scan each node and find the values of each node contained with the same Column Row and MiniGrid and eliminate them from the Node's arraylist of possible values.

The sort board values method then checks if the arraylist in the node is 1 value in size, and if it is, it sets the value of that node to that last value in the Arraylist.

```
    public void sortBoardVals() {
    for (Node n : cells) {
        if (n.posVals.size() == 1) {
            if (n.value == 0)
                n.value = n.posVals.get(0);
        }
    }
}

public void scanColumn(Node n) {
    for (Node node : cells) {
        ArrayList<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (node.get_COL_ID() == n.get_COL_ID()) {
            toRemove.add(node.getValue());
        }

        n.posVals.removeAll(toRemove);

    }

}

public void scanRow(Node n) {
    for (Node node : cells) {
        ArrayList<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (node.get_ROW_ID() == n.get_ROW_ID()) {
            toRemove.add(node.getValue());
        }

        n.posVals.removeAll(toRemove);

    }
}

public void scanMiniGrid(Node n) {
    for (Node node : cells) {
        ArrayList<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (node.get_MG_ID() == n.get_MG_ID()) {
            toRemove.add(node.getValue());
        }
        n.posVals.removeAll(toRemove);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the number of nodes is constant, you should use Node[] instead of ArrayList<Node>. Similarly, you should use boolean[] instead of ArrayList<Integer> to represent possible values (for each value, true = possible, false = impossible)

Comment: Had not though of it that way, looks to me like I am gonna have to reconsider the data structure completely, thank you.

Comment: @Saposhiente That's pretty minor stuff. I don't see how either of those changes would make this any easier.

Comment: @JohnKugelman It's not a solution, but it makes it more efficient. That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the second pane, looks like you take a copy of cells and call it 'before'.

Then you're comparing the items in cells and before, so without knowing what the functions within CRME do, the simple answer seems to be that cells and before are equal.

I also don't know how you're setting up the actual puzzle. You do realise that for plenty of cells in a mostly-unsolved Sudoku the value won't be constrained, right?

I would start by setting up a puzzle that's complete except for one cell, then following your code through the debugger as it tries to solve that cell.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, it would clearer if I showed them too, it's 5 am and I am very tired haha